# Symfony 4 : Cannot autowire argument $manager of ... it references interface "Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

when i submit my form i got this error :

> Cannot autowire argument $manager of "App\Controller\AdController::create()": it references interface "Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager" but no such service exists. You should maybe alias this interface to the existing "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager" service.

This is in function create in AdController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Ad;
use App\Form\AdType;
use App\Repository\AdRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class AdController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/ads", name="ads_index")
     */
    public function index(AdRepository  $repo)
    {
        $ads = $repo->findAll();

        return $this->render('ad/index.html.twig', [
            'ads' => $ads,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/ads/new", name="ads_create")
     * 
     * @return Response
     */

    public function create(Request $request, ObjectManager $manager){
        $ad = new Ad();



        $form = $this->createForm(AdType::class, $ad);

        $form->handleRequest($request);//symfony va faire le lien entre les donne des champs fu formulaire et la variable $ad

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() ){
            $manager->persist($ad);
            $manager->flush();
        }

        return $this->render("ad/new.html.twig", [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }

    /**  
     * @Route("/ads/{slug}", name="ads_show")
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show(Ad $ad){
        return $this->render('ad/show.html.twig', [
            'ad' => $ad
        ]);
    }
}
```

and this is my AdType.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Ad;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\UrlType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\MoneyType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;

class AdType extends AbstractType

{

/**
 * @param string $label
 * @param string $placeholder
 * @return array
 */
private function getConfiguration($label, $placeholder){
    return [
        'label' => $label,
        'attr' => [
            'placeholder' => $placeholder
        ]
    ];
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title', TextType::class, $this->getConfiguration("titre", "tapez un super titre pour votre annonce"))
        ->add('slug', TextType::class, $this->getConfiguration("Adresse web", "tapez l'adresse web (automatique)"))
        ->add('coverImage', UrlType::class, $this->getConfiguration("Url de l'image principal", "Donnez l'adresse d'une image qui donne vraiment envie"))
        ->add('introduction', TextType::class, $this->getConfiguration("introduction", "donnez une description global de l'annonce"))
        ->add('content', TextareaType::class, $this->getConfiguration("Description detaille", "tapez une description qui donne vraiment envie de venir chez vous !"))
        ->add('price', MoneyType::class, $this->getConfiguration("Prix par nuit", "indiquez le prix que voulez pour une nuit"))
        ->add('rooms', IntegerType::class, $this->getConfiguration("Nombre de chambre", "le nom de chambres disponibles"))
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Ad::class,
    ]);
}
```

}

Why i get this error when i submit my form and how can i solve this problem

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 9):

You should avoid using directly the service. Always use the contract instead.
It is available for every services

So instead of using `ObjectManager` directly, use `EntityManagerInterface`

Comment: Just for info, Doctrine is not completely consistent when using the suffix Interface.  ObJectManager is indeed an interface.  EntityManagerInterface extends it.  Doctrine actually supports some non-sql persistence mechanisms.  Most of the time it makes sense to use EntityManagerInterface but your reasoning is off.

Answer (score 5):

The error actually says you should alias that class to an existing service. That happens when Symfony does not know which implementation of interface you are going to use.

Try something like this:

```
Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager: '@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager'
```

Add it in services.yml and try.

docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#using-aliases-to-enable-autowiring

Comment: i added it to my service.yml but i still get same error !

Comment: Sorry did not read that error right. Error actually says you should alias that class to a existing service. That happens when symfony does not know which implementation of that interface you going to use. I will update answer.

Answer (score 1):

use `ManagerRegistry` service instead of `ObjectManager`

```
/**
 * @Route("/ads/new", name="ads_create")
 * 
 * @return Response
 */

public function create(Request $request, ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry){
    $ad = new Ad();

    $form = $this->createForm(AdType::class, $ad);

    $form->handleRequest($request);//symfony va faire le lien entre les donne des champs fu formulaire et la variable $ad

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() ){
        $em = $managerRegistry->getManager();
        $em->persist($ad);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render("ad/new.html.twig", [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class Someclass {
protected $em;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
{
    $this->em = $entityManager;
}

public function somefunction() {
    $em = $this->em;
    ...
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must change this use:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
```

to this use:

```
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
$manager->persist($ad);
$manager->flush();
```

To this

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entityManager->flush();
```

Comment: Why did you add this answer [twice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65472831/354577)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `EntityManagerInterface` instead of `ObjectManager`.

Answer (score -2):

You must change this:

```
$manager->persist($ad);
$manager->flush();
```

To this:

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entityManager->flush();
```